# Cypher relationships + paths and lucene

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The issue here is that I'm using a path (p=) to select various relationships down a path, I thought by having them start with a common reserved pre-term (has_..) I could make assumptions using Neo4j's lucene syntax in the WHERE clause, however when using paths (p=) we are returned a collection, thus making the WHERE unable to define what's in the MATCH. Maybe there are other options?

```
MATCH (se:SourceExtended {name: 'BASE_NODE'})
WITH se
MATCH p =(:Trim)-[r:has_publication|has_model|has_trim|has_dealer|extends*1..5]-(se)
//WHERE type(r)=~ 'has_.*' OR type(r) = 'extends'  <-Fails because p is a collection!!!
WITH se, p LIMIT 1
RETURN extract(n in nodes(p) | labels(n)) as labels, extract(r in relationships(p) | r) as relationships
```

UPDATE: Based on Dave Bennett's suggestion I can do:

```
MATCH (se:SourceExtended {source: 'XPRIMA_SPEC'})
WITH se
MATCH p =(:Brand)-[r*1..5]-(se)
WHERE ANY(r in relationships(p) WHERE type(r)=~ 'has_.*' OR type(r) = 'extends')
WITH se, p LIMIT 1
RETURN extract(n in nodes(p) | labels(n)) as labels, extract(r in relationships(p) | r) as relationships
```

However I'm surprised that the queries have now gone from ~500 ms up to ~3200 ms. Starting to think that dynamically adding all the relationship types while building the query might be the only solution.

Comment: I think the nature of what you are doing is inherently much more expensive.   Keeping the types in the path will likely match fewer things.  By matching all types and filtering them in the where clause you are likely matching more paths and then having to filter them afterwards.  You will be able to gain some insight by using "profile" in the neo4j-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do something like this...

```
...
WHERE ANY(r in relationships(p) WHERE type(r)=~ 'has_.*' OR type(r) = 'extends')
...
```

but why would you need to do that since your path relationship already contains only relationship types that match the terms in the desired where clause.

Comment: I should have mentioned that over time, more and more relationships will be added with "has_..." and I don't want to modify the code every time. The "has_..." is reserved if you will. Probably a better design would be to simply define them as "has" relationships and add properties, not sure yet, but thanks for the answer, I'll try it out.